# Adding objects to a rotated Group

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

When I add an object to a group that is rotated in FabricJS it doesn't respect the angle of the other objects.

Steps to reproduce:

- Select an object
- Click add to group
- Select group
- Click Rotate group
- Click add to group

The group now contains objects that have different angles.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});
canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#f55'
}));

$("#rotate").on("click", function() {
  var currentObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var currentAngle = currentObject.angle;
  var adjustedAngle = currentAngle + 90;

  if (adjustedAngle >= 360) {
    adjustedAngle = 0;
  }
  currentObject.setAngle(adjustedAngle);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$("#add").on('click', function() {
  if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var object;

    console.log(activeObject.type);

    if (activeObject.type == "triangle") {

      object = fabric.util.object.clone(activeObject);

      object.top = activeObject.top;
      object.left = activeObject.left + 25;
      object.fill = "#0000FF";

      var tempAngle = activeObject.angle;

      activeObject.angle = 0;
      object.angle = 0;

      var group = new fabric.Group([activeObject, object], {
        angle: tempAngle
      });

      canvas.add(group);
      canvas.setActiveObject(group);
      canvas.remove(activeObject);

    } else {
      var activeGroup = activeObject;
      var lastAddedObject = activeGroup.getObjects()[activeGroup.size() - 1];
      object = fabric.util.object.clone(lastAddedObject);

      object.set('top', lastAddedObject.top + activeGroup.top + activeGroup.height / 2);
      object.set('left', lastAddedObject.left + activeGroup.left + activeGroup.width / 2 + 25);

      console.log(lastAddedObject.angle);


      activeGroup.addWithUpdate(object);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }


  }

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.0-rc.1/fabric.js"></script>

<button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
<button id="add">Add to Group</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, rather than just on a jsbin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my question with the code snippet and added additional information.

Comment: please update to latest version and you should be fine.

Comment: I still have the issue using FabricJS v1.6.0 rc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I linked the latest version where adding items to rotated group works.

I do not really understand what effect you are trying to achieve.
If group has angle of 30, when you add an object with angle of 0, it will not be rotated.

if you want an object to jump in a rotated group and be rotated as the other, you have to add some calculations. In those calculations you have to consider that everytime you use addWithUpdate the group is destroyed and created again and that reset the angle to 0.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});
canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  fill: '#f55'
}));

$("#rotate").on("click", function() {
  var currentObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var currentAngle = currentObject.angle;
  var adjustedAngle = currentAngle + 90;

  if (adjustedAngle >= 360) {
    adjustedAngle = 0;
  }
  currentObject.setAngle(adjustedAngle);
  canvas.renderAll();
});

$("#add").on('click', function() {
  if (canvas.getActiveObject()) {
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    var object;

    console.log(activeObject.type);

    if (activeObject.type == "triangle") {

      object = fabric.util.object.clone(activeObject);

      object.top = activeObject.top;
      object.left = activeObject.left + 25;
      object.fill = "#0000FF";

      var tempAngle = activeObject.angle;

      activeObject.angle = 0;
      object.angle = 0;

      var group = new fabric.Group([activeObject, object], {
        
      });

      canvas.add(group);
      canvas.setActiveObject(group);
      canvas.remove(activeObject);

    } else {
      var activeGroup = activeObject;
      var lastAddedObject = activeGroup.getObjects()[activeGroup.size() - 1];
      object = fabric.util.object.clone(lastAddedObject);

      object.set('top', lastAddedObject.top + activeGroup.top + activeGroup.height / 2);
      object.set('left', lastAddedObject.left + activeGroup.left + activeGroup.width / 2 + 25);
      //object.set('angle', activeObject.angle);

      activeGroup.addWithUpdate(object);
      canvas.renderAll();
    }


  }

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.deltalink.it/andreab/fabric/fabric.js"></script>

<button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
<button id="add">Add to Group</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrea. I think the version of FabricJS you linked to fixed the issue with the rotated groups.

Comment: is the latest build from github + fix for the bug you made stand out.